# How to print in following output

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk

I have this data with me:

```
Order:479959,60=20130624-09:45:02.046|35=D|11=884|38=723|21=1|1=30532|10=085|59=0|114=Y|56=MBT|40=1|43=Y|100=MBTX|55=/GCQ3|49=11342|54=1|8=FIX.4.4|34=388|553=2453|9=205|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|
Order:24780,100=MBTX|43=Y|40=1|34=388|553=2453|52=2013062409:45:02.046|9=205|49=11342|54=1|8=FIX.4.4|55=/GCQ3|11=405|35=D|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|56=MBT|59=0|114=Y|10=085|21=1|38=470|1=30532|
Order:799794,55=/GCQ3|49=11342|54=1|8=FIX.4.4|34=388|553=2453|9=205|52=2013062409:45:02.046|40=1|43=Y|100=MBTX|38=350|21=1|1=30532|10=085|59=0|114=Y|56=MBT|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|35=D|11=216|
Order:72896,11=735|35=D|60=2013062409:45:02.046|56=MBT|59=0|114=Y|10=085|1=30532|38=17|21=1|100=MBTX|43=Y|40=1|553=2453|9=205|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|34=388|8=FIX.4.4|54=1|49=11342|55=/GCQ3|
```

And output should be like this:-

```
Order-479959 38= 723 Clientid=884
Order-24780 38= 470 Clientid=405
Order-799794 38= 350 Clientid=216
Order-72896 38= 17 Clientid=735
```

And my script is this:

```
while read number;do
var=$(sed  's/,.*//')
var2=$(sed 's/^.*[,|]11=\([^|]*\).*$/client id = \1/');
var3=$(sed 's/^.*[,|]38=\([^|]*\).*$/38  = \1/');
echo "$var"
echo "$var2"
echo "$var3"
#echo "$var,$var2,$var3"
done <report.txt
```

But somehow only $var is printing not the other ones. Why? Any suggestion/solution?

Comment: Your fundamental issue with your approach is that you are apparently not inputting `$number` to any of the `sed` commands. However the `while ... read` loop is not really necessary, as far as I can see.

Comment: could plz tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 2 cases:

1. the `38=` field comes before the `11=` (`Clientid`) field
2. the `38=` field comes after the `11=` (`Clientid`) field

Therefore a KISS way to process the file is

```
sed -E \
  -e 's/(Order):([0-9]*).*[,|]38=([0-9]*).*[,|]11=([0-9]*).*/\1-\2 38= \3 Clientid=\4/' \
  -e 's/(Order):([0-9]*).*[,|]11=([0-9]*).*[,|]38=([0-9]*).*/\1-\2 38= \4 Clientid=\3/' \
  report.txt
```

Testing:

```
$ sed -E \
>   -e 's/(Order):([0-9]*).*[,|]38=([0-9]*).*[,|]11=([0-9]*).*/\1-\2 38= \3 Clientid=\4/' \
>   -e 's/(Order):([0-9]*).*[,|]11=([0-9]*).*[,|]38=([0-9]*).*/\1-\2 38= \4 Clientid=\3/' \
>   report.txt
Order-479959 38= 723 Clientid=884
Order-24780 38= 470 Clientid=405
Order-799794 38= 350 Clientid=216
Order-72896 38= 17 Clientid=735
```